# How to set up Z3 solver on Travis-CI machine

Tags: java, travis-ci, z3, continuous-testing

I have a project using library Z3 solver, and want to apply Travis-CI for continuous testing. However, I could not set up z3 on the remote machine in Travis-CI.

Here is further information about my project:

- Created from IDE Eclipse Mars
- Use JDK 8
- Use Ant to buid **build.xml**

The content file **.travis.yml**

```
 language: java
 sudo: enabled
 jdk:
   - oraclejdk8
 before_install:
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get install z3 -y
 script:
 - ant build
 - ant 'MyJUnitTest'
```

The output on the remote machine console

```
... (be removed for clarity)
$ sudo apt-get install z3 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package z3
The command "sudo apt-get install z3 -y" failed and exited with 100 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

I have understood that the problem could be solved by adding the repository containing Z3 solver to **.travis.yml** (section *before_install*). I found one repository: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/z3. However, this repository does not work anymore. More clearly, after 10 minutes (default waiting time on Travis-CI machine), there is no response from this repository.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hvr/z3

More info: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/z3
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received
The build has been terminated
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no official/supported way to do this. It would be nice if there was a maintained repo indeed. But it is possible to do so with some hacking, by directly pulling down the releases and installing them on the build machine.

## Using Nightly Z3 builds

Z3 folks do maintain nightly-builds on github, so it is indeed possible to pull the latest code and integrate it with Travis-CI (for Linux and Mac) and also Appveyor (for Windows).

As an example of how to do this in travis, see:

https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv/blob/master/.travis.yml#L46-L66

For Appveyor setup, see:

https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv/blob/master/.appveyor.yml#L10-L13

Depending on your exact needs, you should be able to adopt this to your own problem. (Note that the travis bit is doing a bit more than z3 by installing some other dependencies on Mac; you should leave those out. Ping if you need help!)

### A note on stability

Unfortunately, this trick is not 100% fool-proof, and it does need occasional maintenance as it relies on where Z3 is stored, how the nightly builds are named, how travis/appveyor handle environment etc; but it has worked for me rather reliably for quite some time now. Good luck!

## Using Stable Z3 versions

If you want the "stable" build instead of "nightly" z3, you can use a similar trick by modifying the locations slightly; by essentially getting them from: https://github.com/Z3Prover/bin/tree/master/releases instead of https://github.com/Z3Prover/bin/tree/master/nightly